# PDO select all data from table with "where" clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to pass $variable parameter to php function and according to this parameter get data from table. This parameter can be null, which means that db request should take all data from the table or it can be int value. Here is the code I try:

```
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ki_cities 
                              WHERE id IS NULL OR id = :user");
$stmt->bindValue(':user',$variable,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This query doesn't return any row.

Here is implicit question for those who are confused by my question.
I want sql query:

```
 SELECT * FROM ki_cities WHERE id = *
```

this query should do the same as:

```
 SELECT * FROM ki_cities
```

I suppose my question is clear.

=======================================

Here is my twisted "solution" if someone interested:

```
$que = "SELECT * FROM ";
            $que = $que . " ki_students where season=4";
            if($type!=null) { $que = $que . " and type =".$type; }
            if($city!=null) { $que = $que . " and city =".$city; }
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($que);
            $stmt->execute();
             $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
             return $result;
```

Comment: You say "I suppose my question is clear." but you didn't ask any questions

Comment: Well you say it... 'I want to pass $variable parameter to php function'. So why don't you create one and give it a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your "question" right, the code can be:

```
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `ki_cities` WHERE ((:user IS NULL) OR (`id` = :user));');
$stmt->bindValue(':user', $variable, is_null($variable) ? PDO::PARAM_NULL : PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

(or you can omit argument #3 to bindValue() and let PDO autodetect data type)

There are 2 possible cases here:

1. :user is NULL - in SQL, first condition matches, all rows are returned;
2. :user is integer - in SQL, second condition matches, one row is returned (provided that id is a unique column).

Answer (score 0):

The statement does not return any rows as it makes very little sense.

Maybe this would be a better way of thinking about that situation

```
if ( empty($variable) ) {
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ki_cities");
} else {
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ki_cities WHERE id = :user");
    $stmt->bindValue(':user',$variable,PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Yes, but I will have many "where" clauses in this query and therefore many combinations where parameters will be null or will have any value. In this case your approach should be not optimal.

Comment: In that case you are not designing your system correctly, or not understanding how to write code properly.

Comment: I thought maybe there was any straight way to do this. If there is no straight way I have one idea how to handle this otherwise.

Comment: Its difficult to know how to be constructive as we only know what you tell us and thats not much in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For prepared statements you always have to generate them in a "literal" way, so that does not let you avoid the process which RiggsFolly describes. If you want an "optimal" solution you can ask if a variable is null in other ways. Eg: as this thread explains.

[Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865747/pdo-prepared-statement-with-optional-parameters)

Hope it helps you